# TS-1068 and TS-1442

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

I have a class which has a member
`public offerTags: [ 'Array' ].<ITag>;`
The above line is throwing error `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)` and `Expected '=' for property initializer.ts(1442)` . This code is auto-generated from protobufjs models.
The editor is not able to understand the above format. Is there a specific TS setting or version that I should make so that I don't get the above error?

```
interface ITag {      
  /** Tag namespace */ 
  namespace?: (string|null);      

  /** Tag name */
  name?: (string|null); 
} 
class Offer {      
  /** Offer id. */     
  public id?: string;      

  /** Offer name. */     
  public name?: string;       
 
  /** Offer offerTags. */     
  public offerTags: [ 'Array' ].<ITag>;      

  /** Offer validityInterval. */     
  public validityInterval?: (IAbsoluteTimeInterval|null); 
}
```

In the above class definition for Offer,  `public offerTags: [ 'Array' ].<ITag>;` is throwing error Expected '=' for property initializer.ts(1442) and Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068).

To me the syntax for offerTags attribute looks odd, ideally an array would be declared as `public offerTags: ITag[]` . Because of the above issue I'm not able to access the attributes declared after `offerTags` attribute such as `validityInrerval`.

Comment: Could you please post the code and the complete error trace?

Comment: @Ben I've updated the post with code and more details. TIA for your help

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in protobufjs and someone else reported the same issue here: [generated .d.ts syntax error #1306](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/1306)

Based on the thread, it seems related to JSDoc < 3.6.1. Current protobfjs version (6.10.2) depends on JSDoc 3.6.3, so I guess it should be working fine with that latest version.

For further analysis, you would have to publish a small reproducible sample.

Comment: There is another bug with v6.10.2 in which not all interfaces are generated from the protobuf models because of jsdoc version >3.6. https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/1222 . So it seems any version of protobufjs is having an issue with generated TS.